# How to add SMACK rule for controlling mmap of shared lib via SMACK64MMAP extended attribute

Tags: mandatory-access-control

I am new to [SMACK](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/Smack.txt) and trying to explore SMACK64MMAP attribute and how it works. Basically, I want to control which process can map my shared library.

Hence, I am adding a label to SMACK64MMAP attribute of my shared library file. After this, no process can map my shared lib which is expected as per SMACK behaviour.

Now, I want to add a rule for my process to enable my process to bind to shared lib. I tried adding multiple SMACK rules to enable access from my process to shared lib but all the time it's giving error that mmap is failing.

Does anyone know how to add SMACK access rule to allow process to bind to shared lib which has SMACK64MMAP label assigned?